# Fade Out/In elements in jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 list items which are being changed every X seconds with carsoul, each item is consist of one img as background, one h1 and one p tag.

With below code I was able to animate text but it does not looks good in IE, it change the text of h1/p before fading out by using opacity:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide', function() {
//Fading out 
    $(".carousel-caption h1").animate({'left': '-=500px', 'opacity': 0}, 1000); 
    $(".carousel-caption p").animate({'right': '-=500px', 'opacity': 0}, 1000);
// Fading In
    $(".carousel-caption h1").animate({'left': '+=500px', 'opacity': 1}, 1000);     
    $(".carousel-caption p").animate({'right': '+=500px', 'opacity': 1}, 1000); 
});
```

Any better way to fade out then fade In elements? Thanks for any input

Comment: What type of effect are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want the `h1` and `p` to completely fade out before the next set?

Comment: which version of IE do you need it to work in?

Comment: Plz see example here http://jsfiddle.net/ww67B/3/, @Evan i am using IE9

Comment: above example looks great in chrome but IE fade In new element before fading out old one and firefox is dislocation p position.